# Replace asterisk (*) with my own HTML in twig-templates

Tags: templating

I'm working on a Craft CMS website and I need help with formatting the H1 tag.

I would like to be able to easily outline some parts of the title, like in the example below.

Ideally by adding an asterisk (*) to the actual title, like so:

`Website laten maken *Amsterdam*`

I already have the HTML set up, which just uses a span with a class:

`<h1>Website laten maken <span class="text-outline">Amsterdam</span></h1>`

I've already tried to replace the asterisks with the span by using Twig's `replace` but this didn't work with replacing the closing tag.

Is there a way (for example a regex) that allows me to do this? And is there a way to wrap this in a function so I can reuse it?

Many thanks!

[image: Example of what I want to do]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilites to solve this. The fastest, as you said, is a regular expression, but those always come with limitations and potential performance issues. You can make this very simple or very complicated – it depends on how many of those special formatting options you want to include for your fields, and how often they will be used.

For a 'full' solution, you're looking at something like [WordPress shortcodes](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-shortcodes/). Those come with start and end tags, shortocde attributes and nested shortcodes. But you're probably not gonna need that much.

---

Let's consider a simple solution. For a start, I highly recommend using different symbols to denote start and end of the highlighting. Otherwise, you're entering a world of pain – the regex is gonna break if your editors want to highlight multiple phrases in the same field. I would suggest something like this:

```
Website laten maken {Amsterdam}
```

Given this syntax, you don't even need RegEx:

```twig
{% set text = '<h1>Website</h1> laten maken {Amsterdam}' %}
{{ text|replace({
    '{': '<span class="text-outline">',
    '}': '</span>',
})|striptags('<span>') }}
```

Note the `striptags` at the end that only allows `<span>` tags – this prevents your editors from entering raw HTML (otherwise you'd have to use the `raw` filter to prevent the span tags from being escaped).

If at some point you need to allow literal brackets (`{`, `}`) in the text, you can just use multiple brackets as delimiters instead: `{{{`, `}}}`

For comparison, here's the same replacement done with RegEx, which allows you to better handle some edge-cases (like start delimiters without a matching end delimiter or vice-versa):

```twig
{% set text = 'Website laten maken {Amsterdam}' %}
{{ text|replace(
    '/\{([^\}]+)\}/',
    '<span class="text-outline">$1</span>',
)|striptags('<span>') }}
```

To make this reusable, I would put that function in a [custom Twig extension](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/extending-twig.html#register-a-twig-extension) so it can be used everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace with regex also, maybe like this :

```
{{ "Website laten maken *Amsterdam*"|replace('/\\*([^\\s][^*\\n]+[^\\s])\\*/', '<span class="text-outline">$1</span>')|raw }}
```

You can wrap this code inside [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html), so you can reuse the code.